# container startup probe does not get executed

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have defined a startup probe for the container and deployed it in openshift. openshift version is 3.11
it seems the startup probe does not get executed.

```
startupProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - echo "start up probe" > /tmp/startup
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 300
  failureThreshold: 1
```

what i expect from the below definition of startup probe is to have the file /tmp/startup created.
but when i log to the POD to check i do not see any file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "startupProbe" on OpenShift 3.11 which is based on Kubernetes 1.11,
because the feature provides from Kubernetes 1.18 (as beta).
So you need OpenShift 4.5(incorporated with Kubernetes 1.18) for using the feature by default at least.
Refer [Feature Gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/).

```
Feature         Default   Stage   Since   Until
-----------------------------------------------------------
StartupProbe    false     Alpha   1.16    1.17  
StartupProbe    true      Beta    1.18
```